# xpath: how can you select a specific text node before and after a <br> tag?

Tags: xpath, nokogiri

consider this

List of Alcohol

```
Beer
<br>
Vodka
<br>
rum
<br>
whiskey
```

how would you express Beer in xpath ?

```
/br/preceding-sibling::text() ?
```

what about vodka ? rum ?

Comment: Have you considered a DOM parser instead of an XML parser? Your example is not valid XML, for one.

Answer (score 8):

Depends on the context.  Ideally, to be well-formed XML, your sequence needs a root element.  Let's say it's `<bar/>`.

Beer: `/bar/br[1]/preceding-sibling::text()[1]`

Vodka:  `/bar/br[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]`

Rum: `/bar/br[2]/following-sibling::text()[1]`

Comment: where can i add the normalize-space function ?